# Why do my web images have unintended black borders?

Tags: html, css, web, jekyll

I am building my GitHub page with Jekyll and I have found out that in small screens (iPhone SE), images have a black border in some of them sides.

[image]

I am not very experienced in web development, but I know that the CSS style is this:

```css
.post-preview .post-image-small {
    display: block;
}
```

In bigger screens I am not having this issue, such as MacBook Pro screen.

Comment: You could try adding - .post-preview .post-image-small {
    display: block;
    border: none;
}

Comment: Thank you @FujiRoyale, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @PedroPicapiedra look at the develop tools in browser. which class is overriding it. learn obout specificity in css and you will fix this problem easy

Comment: Do your source images have transparency or have a border?

Comment: @Phix they have transparency.

Comment: Hmm maybe convert to a format without transparency since they're on a solid background anyway or try setting a background color of white to the container?

Comment: Ok @Phix I am trying that. Thanks.

Comment: @Phix the border is still there, but this time, only in the bottom. Not in the right side of the image.